# Authorization failure calling MobileFirst Adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

Not sure whether the same issue has been raised before (I tried to comment but was unable to do so - see link below)

Anyway, I've just upgraded my development environment to MobileFirst Studio 7.1 and I'm having an issue with the adapters we created in 7.0. The adapters deploy without error but when I try to call WL.Client.invokeProcedure from my browser (I'm just testing as a web app at the moment) I get an error 500 in the browser console.

I've tested the adapters using the "Run As ... > Call MobileFirst Adapter" menu option, and they work so this is only related to accessing the adapters from a client. The exception output in the MobileFirst Development Server console is:

[ERROR   ] FWLSE0335E: Authorization failed: ClientId WbWBHC11bK was not found on the server. [project BusinessEnergy]
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0048E: Unhandled exception caught: null
com.worklight.authorization.endpoint.OauthAuthorizationException
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthorizationFilterUtils.isAuthorizedClient(AuthorizationFilterUtils.java:63)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthorizationFilterUtils.isSessionIndependentSupportedClient(AuthorizationFilterUtils.java:49)
    at com.worklight.core.auth.impl.AuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AuthenticationFilter.java:197)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:206)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:86)
    at com.worklight.analytics.AnalyticsFilter.doFilter(AnalyticsFilter.java:124)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:206)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:86)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:978)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.invokeFilters(WebAppFilterManager.java:1100)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.handleRequest(WebApp.java:4845)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.handleRequest(DynamicVirtualHost.java:297)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:981)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.osgi.DynamicVirtualHost$2.run(DynamicVirtualHost.java:262)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.dispatcher.internal.channel.HttpDispatcherLink$TaskWrapper.run(HttpDispatcherLink.java:955)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
 [project BusinessEnergy]
com.worklight.authorization.endpoint.OauthAuthorizationException

I wondered whether something basic has changed with authentication in v7.1 but a colleague who created the new v7.1 project is running without this issue.

[same question in a separate thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32515262/how-to-solve-com-worklight-authorization-endpoint-oauthauthorizationexception)

Answer (score 4):

Found a resolution to my issue which was basically to clear the cookie cache in my browser. I don't have a requirement at the moment to view multiple apps in the same browser so I may not hit the other issue you mentioned Idan (thanks for your quick response though)

Answer (score 1):

This is possibly the same issue as reported in the following APAR: *PI48842  Previewing multiple applications in the same browser causing client authentication issues*.

The APAR description is not similar to yours, but the error and exception in the stack trace are exactly the same.

> [ERROR   ] FWLSE0335E: Authorization failed: ClientId xjoWZVkUrR was
>   not found on the server. [project test]
>
> [ERROR   ] FWLSE0048E: Unhandled exception caught: null
>   com.worklight.authorization.endpoint.OauthAuthorizationException

If you are an IBM customer you can open a PMR (support ticket) and request a fix for this issue once it is available.