# Insertion not happening in ibm mobile first sql adapter

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I am trying to insert data into existing table in database from mobilefirst. the adapter is working fine and i can insert data into database from the adapter. But when it is invoked in client side it shows failure message.

```
function insert(){
    var invocationData = {
              adapter:"sqlad",
                 procedure:"procedure1",
                 parameters:[$('#empid').val(),$('#empname').val()]
            };


    WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData,{
        onSuccess :loadFeedsSuccess,
       onFailure :loadFeedsFailure,
    });
   }

   function loadFeedsSuccess() {

   alert("success");


    }

   function loadFeedsFailure() {
   alert("failure");

   }
```

html

```
<body style="display: none;">
            <!--application UI goes here-->
            <h1>ENTER THE EMP DETAILS</h1>
            EMP ID<input type="text" id=empid> <br> <br>
            Emp NAME<input type="text" id=empname><br> <br>
            <input type="submit" value=register onclick="insert();">
            <script src="js/initOptions.js"></script>
            <script src="js/main.js"></script>
            <script src="js/messages.js"></script>
        </body>
```

adap imp.js

```
var procedure1Statement = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("INSERT INTO testdemo(empid,empname) Values(?,?)");
function procedure1(empid,empname) {
    return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
        preparedStatement : procedure1Statement,
        parameters : [empid,empname]
    });
}
```

Comment: That i cant idan but last month a team from ibm had shown an demo of mobile first and my company assigned me (am a fresher just got the job) to learn this and present an appliacation as they are planning to buy one .why you ask all this

Comment: Are you the only one in your company working on this? You keep asking the ***exact*** same questions as this person: http://stackoverflow.com/users/4525003/vikram-srinivasan

Comment: i do no @IdanAdar about him i am learning daily and asking if any doubt arises.In my company i do no abt other probably no one other than me assigned to ibm tool

Comment: I'm gessing he's asking because he does 'Customer-Oriented R&D @ IBM in the MobileFirst Platform team' :p

Comment: @raman What is your actual question?

Comment: alert message from loadsfeedfailure is executed

Comment: When you preview the application in Chrome, make sure the Chrome DevTools is open with the Console tab. Refresh the page and click the button. What do you see there? You have "been instructed" on this debugging path in your previous questions.

Comment: my actual question is not able to insert data from client side code(index.html and main.js) into the database.i have 2 fields emp id and name .from adapter if i give values it gets stored in my database but from client side code is not working @EmanuelEy

Comment: @raman, focus on my questions and answer them. Fully. Of course you'll get the alert, because that's what you put in your client code. But just an alert *is not helpful*. You need the *actual* error.

Comment: POST http://192.168.5.84:10080/simpledb/apps/services/api/simple/common/query 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: [/simpledb/apps/services/api/simple/common/query] failure. state: 500, response: The server was unable to process the request from the application. Please try again later.

Comment: i am actually getting the same error posted here https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014912685#77777777-0000-0000-0000-000014912685

Comment: Try 2 things: 1) restart the development server (Eclipse); 2) delete the workspace, try again. As the error clearly states, it's not about the code but the server. 3) Double check your database connectivity settings in the adapter XML. 4) Check the server logs in eclipse-workspace\MobileFirstServerConfig\servers\worklight\logs\messages.log

Comment: actually what am supposed to look at messages.log for ??

Comment: this is wat i found in mobile first server console[ERROR   ] FWLSE0335E: Authorization failed: ClientId 8v2iz67uij was not found on the server. [project simpledb]
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0048E: Unhandled exception caught: null
com.worklight.authorization.endpoint.OauthAuthorizationException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The actual failure here is this:

> [ERROR ] FWLSE0335E: Authorization failed: ClientId 8v2iz67uij was not
>   found on the server. [project simpledb] [ERROR ] FWLSE0048E: Unhandled
>   exception caught: null
>   com.worklight.authorization.endpoint.OauthAuthorizationException

The solution is detailed in this question: [Authorization failure calling MobileFirst Adapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32609328/authorization-failure-calling-mobilefirst-adapter)

1. To fully resolve the issue so that it will not appear again, you must update your Studio installation to the latest iFix. As an IBM customer you can download the latest iFix from the IBM Fix Central website using your customer credentials.
2. As a temporary fix you can attempt to clear the browser cookies, as suggested in the linked question.