# MobileFirst Adapter Authorization failed after updating

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I developed app for iPad, and it was working and connecting to MobileFirst(7.1) server.
But I update to 10.3.1(for Mac,iPad OS) and 8.3.2(for XCode) recently.
Then I cannot connect MobileFirst server again, and it displays error message in the console window.

> [ERROR   ]  FWLSE0335E: Authorization failed: CliendId ****************************************  
> was not found on the server.

But the CliendId in the console is not same as my iPad's UDID.
I don't know what the number means.

Please help me if you can solve the error or give me information!!

Comment: Is this similar to the thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32609328/authorization-failure-calling-mobilefirst-adapter ?

Comment: Thank you Kavitha.
I've tried to clear the cookie and cache in browser. But I couldn't resolve this issue.

Comment: Does it work if you uninstall and reinstall the application?

Answer (score 1):

**I deleted app on the iPad then I re-installed the app.

(It was not enough only re-installing)**

I could solve the problem!
Thanks Vivin!!!